# django templates string formatting

Tags: python, django, django-templates, string-formatting

I want to pad and cut too long chars. So I used stringformat. In this example, I want my string to be 10 characters long, with padding if necessary. I have this code in my django template

```
{{ "my too long or too short string"|stringformat:":10" }}
```

But django outputs nothing.

Comment: Did you consider writing a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django `1.10`, docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat),

Use `truncatechars`, `rjust` together.

**index.html**

```
<p>Non formated string</p>
<p>{{ "Truncatechars (include ... length)"|truncatechars:10}}</p>
<p>{{ "Truncatechars with rjust"|truncatechars:10|rjust:"30" }}</p>
<p>{{ "Only rjust"|rjust:"30" }}</p>
```

**Output**

Template renders correct HTML as below.

Please note `white-space: pre;` css property to represent white-space.

```css
p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p>Non formated string</p>
<p>Truncat...</p>
<p>                    Truncat...</p>
<p>                    Only rjust</p>
```

About white-space, see [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/)

Answer (score 0):

Use in-bulit `truncatechars` template tag

```
{{ "my too long or too short string"|truncatechars:10 }}
```

Comment: It does truncate char, but I also want padding if the string is too short